# Add class to <li> element based on container div width

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, width

I have a floated list of images each with a right margin of 10px. I am using jquery to give the last LI element a class of "last" which removes the right margin.

Here's the jQuery I'm using:

```
$('ul.grid_list li:nth-child(3n)').addClass('last');
```

So this one makes it so that each row has 3 LI elements.

What I need to do is have the "last" class to be attached to a different LI element based on how big the container div is.

I use media queries to increase the container div width and it's broken down into 4: 
Mobile (2 LI per row),
Facebook iFrame 520px (3 LI per row),
iPad Portrait (4 LI per row),
960px (5 LI per row)

So basically what it needs to do is something like this....

If  is 960px wide, add "last" to 5th Li child
If  is 520px wide, add "last" to 3rd LI child

I hope that all makes sense. Let me know if you need more detailed info. I am open to adding a different class name to the container div based on window size.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Sorry, in response to one question, the html is set up something like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
...
    <ul class="grid_list">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li class="last"></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
...
</div>
```

With WRAPPER being the container element that gets the size attached to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know which object is your sized container and I'm not sure I understood exactly what you want the logic to be, but assuming the container is `grid_list`, you can do build some logic like this and then incorporate that into a programmatically built selector string:

```
var numPerRow = 3;
var width = $(".grid_list").width();
if (width > 960) {
    numPerRow = 4;
} else if (width > 720) {
    numPerRow = 3;
} else if (width > 520) {
    numPerRow = 2;
} else {
    numPerRow = 1;
}
```

Then, built you selector like this:

```
$('ul.grid_list li:nth-child(' + numPerRow + 'n)').addClass('last');
```

I wasn't sure exactly what your width logic was, but obviously you can adapt this code to your exact width trigger points and num columns.

Or, if an algorithm works based on how many will fit, you could reduce it to a calculation like this:

```
var numPerRow = Math.floor($(".grid_list").width() / 250);
numPerRow = Math.min(numPerRow, 1);
```

To make this code respond to window resize events, you'd do something like this:

```
function setupGrid() {
    $('ul.grid_list li').removeClass('last');
    var numPerRow = 3;
    var width = $(".grid_list").width();
    if (width > 960) {
        numPerRow = 4;
    } else if (width > 720) {
        numPerRow = 3;
    } else if (width > 520) {
        numPerRow = 2;
    } else {
        numPerRow = 1;
    }

    $('ul.grid_list li:nth-child(' + numPerRow + 'n)').addClass('last');
}

$(window).resize(setupGrid);
```

If that gets a little laggy in responsiveness, sometimes it's good to use a short timer on the resize event like this:

```
var timer = null;
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        timer = null;
        setupGrid();
    }, 500);
});
```

This will only do the relayout after the resize event stops for 1/2 second rather than trying to do it live during the resizing.

Comment: I think your comparisons are a bit off, no?

Comment: @You - I didn't really understand what exactly they wanted the rules to be, but I figured they can easily adjust the logic to suit once they see how to programmatically build the selector string from the logic.

Comment: @jfriend00 Your first suggestion works, but now here's another question. Is there a way to get it so it automatically switches it up on resize? Right now you have to refresh the browser, which will work fine except if the person is using a mobile device that can switch between portrait and landscape. Thanks

Comment: @jkilp - you would have to hook the window resize event and run some additional code to reset it when the size changes.  That would involve removing all existing `.last` classes and then running your code again on each resize event.  See http://api.jquery.com/resize/ for more info.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Excellent! I did a little bit of tweaking to it because it would work when I resized, but if I loaded a page width a certain width, it wouldn't add the "last." It would wait until I actually manually resized the browser to start working. However, I got it to work now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach is to add the class to just those who share the same offset as the last item.  In other words, something like...

```
var lastTop = $('ul.grid_list li:eq(-1)').offset().top;
$('ul.grid_list li:eq(-5)').removeClass('last').each(function(index, item) {
     if ($(this).offset().top === lastTop) {
         $(this).addClass('last');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using javascript at all, your better bet is to use the `first-child` CSS selector, which has [full browser compatibility IE7+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2), and then just apply `margin-left` instead of `margin-right`.